# Count all rows for each DISTINCT

Tags: postgresql, query, count, distinct

How can count all rows of WHERE statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT column1 FROM table COUNT WHERE date::text LIKE '%2014%';
```

My output:

```
column1
=======
info1
info2
info3
```

Desired OUTPUT:

```
column1|number_of_rows
=====================
info1  | 2000
info2  | 1500
info3  | 1000
```

Can you support me How can improve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can use [GROUP BY](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) to get distinct column1 values, and instead of convert the date to text you can use [EXTRACT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function for this purpose.

```
select 
    colum1, 
    count(*) as number_of_rows
from 
    your_table
where 
    extract(year from date) = 2014
group by 
    column1;
```

Comment: I'm glad to help